# Node.js server silently fails with Upstart

Tags: upstart

I can manually run my Node.js server with `./server.js`, but when I try to daemonize it with Upstart, it silently fails. Any idea why this would happen?

I tried enabling console logging in the Upstart configuration, and temporarily removed `2>&1`, but I could never get it to produce any log files, either in stdout, stderr, or in `/var/log/upstart/`, `/var/log/message`, etc etc.

Source:

https://github.com/mcandre/node-ios7crypt/

Comment: Can you: remove the custom node path (just use the system one), remove the 2>&1, try to start it, copy any logs you can find? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using [script](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#script) stanza and not [exec](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#exec) stanza? Because of HOME environment variable?

Comment: Upvote for the tip. I dunno, just borrowing code from online tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the way I was writing the Node.js web app code, using paths relative to the web app script that broke when run by upstart.

I added `__dirname + "/"`, and the silent failures became quiet successes.